# How to comment on some input in infopath programmatically?

Tags: c#, infopath, comments

Does anyone have any experience with/or can comment on writing to an infopath form programmatically?

I have a requirement which needs to write and periodically update the InfoPath form. I didn't find any resource that describes how to modify infoPath file programmatically like Word COM.

I prefer to use InfoPath 2007/2010. Thank you for any information you could provide.

Answer (score 0):

An InfoPath XSN is essentially just a [CAB file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabinet_%28file_format%29). So in order to programmatically modify an InfoPath form, you can extract it ([CABLIB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15397/Cabinet-File-CAB-Compression-and-Extraction) is a decent CAB compression library), modify the extracted files, and then re-assemble it into a CAB.

How feasible it would be to modify the form would, however, depend on what kind of modifications you are intending to do.